# Question regarding present perfect

Tags: present-perfect, past-participles

I want to know if these sentences means he is still a teacher or not. Here, is *been* being used as a past participle?

1. He has *been* a teacher.
2. He has *been* a plumber.

Comment: We use "has", not "have", for third-person singular words

Comment: There might be a difference in meaning depending on whether your example sentences are full sentences or whether they are part of larger sentences (like "He has been a teacher for 10 years")

Comment: @rajivDixit, please look closely at the words "particle" and "participle." They are different words with different meanings. In answer to your first question: we do not have enough information to know whether he is still a teacher or a plumber. The sentences tell us only that he was a teacher and plumber at some previous time. The answer to your second question is Yes: "been" is used here as the past participle of the verb "to be." The verb is in the present perfect form.

Comment: The meaning must be inferred from the context in which the sentence appears. See [What is the perfect and how do I use it?](http://ell.stackexchange.com/q/13255/32), especially section [3.2 Pragmatic meaning](http://ell.stackexchange.com/a/13261/32).

Answer (score 1):

A simple way to look at it is that the precise meaning of *been* is sometimes fuzzy, it can mean *became* or *started to be*.

> He has been a teacher.

Without a qualifying time expression, this likely means at one point in the past he was a teacher, but this strongly implies he is not currently.  Sometimes this is emphasized by putting "before" at the end of it - "He has been a teacher before."

> He has been a teacher for six months.

This means that six months ago he became a teacher, and "becoming a teacher" is not happening currently (i.e. he is not a new teacher anymore), but this implies that he is still teaching.

What if we want to say he was a teacher for six months and isn't currently.  This implies he's not teaching now.

> He was a teacher for six months.

Or, less preferable:

> He has been a teacher for six months before (this is awkward sounding but will get the idea across).